# Use plotinum to draw figures with log-scale y-axis

Tags: go

Does anyone have experience using plotinum to draw figures with log-scaled y-axis?

I do not find such examples in plotinum wiki: https://code.google.com/p/plotinum/wiki/Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that an appropriate way for that is to use the property `Scale` of the y-axis as follows:

```
p, err := plot.New()
p.Y.Min = 0.001
p.Y.Max = 100
p.Y.Scale = LogScale
```

See also:

- http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/plotinum/plot#LogScale
- http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/plotinum/plot#Axis

Comment: Awesome! Alex how did you figure it out? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer of AlexAtNet, I can draw histograms (as well as other plots) with y-axis in log-scale.

I share my code snippet here, because `plot.LogScale` panics if any data point has y==0, which, however, might be hard to avoid with real data.  My solution is simply implementing my own `LogScale`.

```
func plotHist(data plotter.Values, title, xLabel, yLabel, imageFile string) {
    log.Printf("Plotting to %s ...", imageFile)

    p, e := plot.New()
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatalf("plot.New failed: %v", e)
    }

    h, e := plotter.NewHist(data, 50)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatalf("plotter.NewHist failed: %v", e)
    }
    p.Add(h)

    p.Title.Text = title
    p.X.Label.Text = xLabel
    p.Y.Label.Text = yLabel
    p.Y.Min = 1
    _, _, _, p.Y.Max = h.DataRange()
    p.Y.Scale = LogScale
    p.Y.Tick.Marker = plot.LogTicks
    p.Add(plotter.NewGrid())

    if e := p.Save(9, 6, imageFile); e != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Cannot save image to %s: %v", imageFile, e)
    }

    log.Printf("Done plotting to %s.", imageFile)
}

func LogScale(min, max, x float64) float64 {
    logMin := ln(min)
    return (ln(x) - logMin) / (ln(max) - logMin)
}

func ln(x float64) float64 {
    if x <= 0 {
        x = 0.01
    }
    return math.Log(x)
}
```

An output image looks like this:

[image]